# Remove blank page generated by JasperReports: how to hide the empty subreport?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I need to remove report pages when it contains nothing.

I have a page that contains blanks, so I want to remove it. I tried everything but the problem persists.

I tried this code:

```
private void removeBlankPage(List<JRPrintPage> pages) {

    for (Iterator<JRPrintPage> i = pages.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
        JRPrintPage page = i.next();
        if (page.getElements().size() == 0)
            i.remove();
    }
}
```

But it never reaches the  `if (page.getElements().size() == 0)` because the element exists and it's blank.(size always!=0)

Now I'm trying to write a *Print When Expression* attribute, so I want to retrieve the preceding text if it's a blank then I'm sure that the page is all blank and in this case I don't print the blank text. So the blank pages disappears

But I can't retrieve the preceding text.

So what do you suggest?

Here's the jrxml of the parent report  :

```
<detail>
    <band height="802" splitType="Stretch">

        <subreport runToBottom="true">
            <reportElement uuid="14905216-11ed-48c5-aa9c-37a425b186d1" x="51" y="267" width="507" height="535"/>
            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource) $P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("//BODYR/BODYR_table/BODYR_line")]]></dataSourceExpression>
            <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PATH} + "BODYR.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
    </band>
</detail>
```

Here's the subreport :

```
<detail>
    <band height="22" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement uuid="79bfae52-ea0f-4f1f-a310-31464cb82f1e" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" mode="Transparent" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="22"/>
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="Arial" size="13"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{LBODY}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
```

Comment: Do you have a *jrxml* (template) or you generate report's design via the *JasperReports API*?

Comment: yes i have a jrxm template and the blank elements belongs to a subreport.

Comment: I think the problem in your template (or both templates). Can you simplify both of them and post them?

Comment: @AlexK you can see edits.

Comment: You can see this post: [remove Empty pages when no data in Subreports](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/531413/remove-empty-pages-when-no-data-subreports)

Comment: Why your *subreport* element on master report is so large (the *height* property is too big)? Can you decrease its height?